# Capturing network activity in android emulator

Tags: android-emulator, tcpdump

I know there are numerous threads on how to capture network traffic using tcpdump, wireshark etc. I tried enabling `-tcpdump emulator1.cap` in `Eclipse > Run Configurations`. But I don't know where
this data is captured. Can someone please let me know the step by step instructions on how to use tcpdump to capture traffic?

Answer (score 5):

It is stored on the PWD of the emulator. If I start the emulator from the command line, like

$ emulator -tcpdump emulator1.cap -avd x86

then I get a nice emulator1.cap file.

Using Eclipse you'd probably like to do an absolute path. 
Try writing  -tcpdump /tmp/emulator1.cap   or -tcpdump C:\emulator1.cap (on Windows)

Answer (score -1):

In my case I tried doing that but I got some emulator warning like:

emulator: WARNING: The -tcpdump flag is not supported in QEMU2 yet and will be ignored.

By the way, the command I issued in the console is /path_to_sdk/sdk/tools/emulator -tcpdump /path_to_save/emulator1.cap -avd Nexus_7_API_22.

Does anyone have ideas about what image or engine does the emulator support tcpdump flag?

Comment: New question? Ask *as a question.* You posted this as an answer to a question asked 4 years ago.

Comment: No @DavidMakogon, I am telling him an answer that the command I issued should work, but does not work as well. Though I find an answer already for both of his question and to my follow up query.